# PInvoke struct with nested struct array

Tags: c#, c, .net, pinvoke, duckdb

I'm trying to PInvoke a method which has a struct parameter with nested struct array pointer. The [c declaration](https://github.com/cwida/duckdb/blob/master/src/include/duckdb.h#L133) looks like this:

```c
duckdb_state duckdb_query(duckdb_connection connection, const char *query, duckdb_result *out_result);

typedef struct {
    void *data;
    bool *nullmask;
    duckdb_type type;
    char *name;
} duckdb_column;

typedef struct {
    idx_t column_count;
    idx_t row_count;
    duckdb_column *columns;
    char *error_message;
} duckdb_result;
```

I declared them in C# like this:

```cs
[DllImport("duckdb.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "duckdb_query")]
public static extern DuckdbState DuckdbQuery(IntPtr connection, string query, out DuckdbResult result);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct DuckdbColumn
    {
        IntPtr data;
        bool nullmask;  
        DuckdbType type;
        string name;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct DuckdbResult
    {
        public long column_count;
        public long row_count;

        public IntPtr columns;
        public string error_message;
    }
```

But when I try to execute the query and read the columns I don't get any meaningful data:

```cs
result = DuckdbQuery(connection, "SELECT * FROM integers", out queryResult);

DuckdbColumn[] columns = new DuckdbColumn[queryResult.column_count];
var queryResultColumns = queryResult.columns;
            
var columnPointer = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(queryResultColumns);
var ptrToStructure = (DuckdbColumn)Marshal.PtrToStructure(columnPointer, typeof(DuckdbColumn));
```

[image: column data]

How should I change the PInvoke declarations so that I can read the columns after executign the query?

There is example c code at: [DuckDB c example](https://github.com/cwida/duckdb/blob/master/examples/embedded-c/main.c#L30)

### Update 1

I can get column names with the following code:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < queryResult.column_count; i++)
{
    var column = (DuckdbColumn)Marshal.PtrToStructure(queryResult.columns + 8 + (Marshal.SizeOf<DuckdbColumn>() + 8) * i, typeof(DuckdbColumn));
    columns[i] = column;
}
```

but `type` field still says `DUCKDB_TYPE_INVALID`

[image] [image]

### Update 2

As suggested by David in his answer I changed `bool nullmask;`to `IntPtr nullmask;` and I can now read column information like this:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < queryResult.column_count; i++)
{
    var column = (DuckdbColumn)Marshal.PtrToStructure(queryResult.columns + Marshal.SizeOf<DuckdbColumn>() * i, typeof(DuckdbColumn));
    columns[i] = column;
}
```

Comment: That's unlikely to be a valid pointer.  Looks like an error code to me.  With type_invalid hinting that you need to interpret it as an error.

Comment: The number of bytes return is the number of columns * number of rows.  So all you need to do is take ptrToStructure and marshal to a byte array.  Then enumerate through the byte array.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't know about that pointer but the query executes successfully and I get the values back. The only thing that doesn't work is getting column type and name

Comment: @jdweng I can get the data using other functions: https://github.com/cwida/duckdb/blob/master/src/include/duckdb.h#L160

The only thing that doesn't work is getting column type and name

Comment: Create a c# enumeration for the TYPE.  Use the github enumeration in link at top of your question and convert to c#.  The default enumeration size in c# is 32 bit (needs to be the same size as c++).  c++ for strings terminates with a '\0' and size is one byte.  In c# a char is a class.  So change the type from string to byte[].

Comment: @jdweng I already have that enum. The `DuckdbResult` also has char* that I have no problem getting in string when I issue a wrong query

Comment: @jdwengI can share a demo project if you are interested

Comment: Don't understand issue.  Invalid type is zero, so maybe the size is wrong and is not 32 bits.  If the type is wrong size then then name will be wrong.  Also I suspect when string is working it is not in the structure posted.  You probably have a LPRSTR which is converting the byte[] to a string.  So you need to look at following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-for-strings#strings-used-in-structures

Comment: @jdweng The string that works is in the `DuckdbResult` struct that I posted.

Comment: You need to get the type working first because the structure is sequential.  You can change the size of the enumeration like this : enum DuckdbType : short

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222982/discussion-between-giorgi-and-jdweng).

Comment: Share the demo project, it'll be easier.

Comment: @SimonMourier Do you want to continue in the above chat ?

Comment: @jdweng I updated my question with my progress.

Comment: @HansPassant I updated the question with my progress

Comment: Interesting!!!  The name starts at byte 8 of each row.  That means the dataptr  (4 bytes) + nullmask + type is 8 bytes (not 12 bytes).

Comment: Your translation of the `char*` fields as`string` is correct

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Can you help me with a similar issue at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72797984/marshalling-native-string-to-net-in-linux ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have translated this field incorrectly

```
bool *nullmask
```

This is not a `bool` it's a pointer. Declare it as

```
IntPtr nullmask;
```

There could be other errors because we can't see all the translations. Additionally, the `+8` in your array access pointer arithmetic looks suspicious.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! How do I get the bool value from the IntPtr?

Comment: So I think that the native code is C++, because `bool` is a C++ type. In C++ on Windows, `bool` is a single byte. Which means you use `bool nullmask = Marshal.ReadByte(col.nullmask) <> 0`. I think!

Comment: Yes, here is the c++ code: https://github.com/cwida/duckdb/blob/master/src/main/duckdb-c.cpp#L129